# Reverse decimal digits in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I reverse the digits of a number **using bitwise?**

input:

```
x = 123;
```

output:

```
x = 321;
```

How Do this?

Comment: Do you mean invert the bits or reverse a string? Inverting the bits means changing 1 to 0 and vice-versa (in a binary value).

Comment: You mean "reverse the decimal digits", not "invert the bits"...

Comment: What do you mean with "bits", as obviously you don't mean bits.

Comment: Why *must* it be bitwise operators? Is this homework?

Comment: `Reverse digits using bitwise`? You don't. Bitwise flips bits, reversing digits reorders collections of bits (bytes). They are different operations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you wanted to make a simple reversal:

```
var x = 123;
var y = x.toString();
var z = y.split("").reverse().join("");
var aa = Number(z);
document.write(aa);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/gV39e/

Comment: So 1000 and 1 get reversed to the same number?

Comment: Good point, @kennebc.  I should have left it at `var z`, as a `string` but I was converting back to a # again.  Didn't anticipate the 1000.  @alex has a solution to that above.

Comment: This could fail. E.g what happens if the input leads to an overflow if you revers it??

Comment: @JasonGennaro what if x is negative integer? if x is -123 result should be -321. but in your case it will be NaN.

Answer (score 19):

That's not inverting bits; that's reversing the order of decimal digits, which is completely different. Here's one way:

```
var x = 123;
var y = 0;
for(; x; x = Math.floor(x / 10)) {
    y *= 10;
    y += x % 10;
}
x = y;
```

If you actually want to invert bits, it's:

```
x = ~x;
```

As a function:

```
function reverse(n) {
    for(var r = 0; n; n = Math.floor(n / 10)) {
        r *= 10;
        r += n % 10;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: usually when this question comes up (almost always in an interview) they expect you to answer this way without converting the number to a string

Comment: @QuentinEngles: People mostly need to do this with integers. Something with a fractional part is probably better done (and maybe even better represented) as a string.

Comment: @minitech Seems about right, but I was hoping to find a mathematical solution for my decimal math. I'm using really big decimals. It's for a good reason. :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is another way...

```
var reversed = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cc2df/).

If you wanted it again as a `Number`, use `parseInt(reversed, 10)`. Keep in mind though, leading `0`s are not significant in a decimal number, and you will lose them if you convert to `Number`.

Answer (score 3):

> you also use this function

```
function myfunction(a){
   var x=a.toString();
   var y= x.split("");
   var z=y.reverse();
   var result=z.join("");
     return result;
```

}
myfunction(123);

Answer (score 2):

Simple and quick solution: Let's assume that you want to reverse a number 4546. You will take the reminder from each division by 10 and append it to the result until the number is > 0. And simultaneously updating the num variable by dividing it by 10.

```
var x = '';
var num = 4546;
while(num>0){
 x = x + (num%10);
 num = parseInt(num/10);
}
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Reversing The Positive/ Negative Integer Number

```
function reverseInt(n) {
 return parseInt(n.toString().split('').reverse().join()) * Math.sign(n)
}
```

> If n is -5, then Math.sign(n)==> will return -1
>
> If n is 5, then Math.sign(n)==> will return 1

Answer (score 1):

Here are reversible array functions in JavaScript that handle integers or strings:

```
function reverse(array)
{
    var left = null;
    var right = null;
    var length = array.length;
    for (left = 0, right = length - 1; left < right; left += 1, right -= 1)
    {
        var temporary = array[left];
        array[left] = array[right];
        array[right] = temporary;
    }
    return array;
}

function toDigitsArrayFromInteger(integer, isReverse)
{
    var digits = [];

    if (integer > 0)
    {
        var floor = window.Math.floor;
        while (integer > 0)
        {
            digits.push(floor(integer % 10));
            integer = floor(integer / 10);
        }

        // Array is populated in reverse order. Un-reverse it to make it normal.
        if (!isReverse)
        {
            digits = reverse(digits);
        }
    }
    else if (integer < 0)
    {
        digits = toDigitsArrayFromInteger(-integer, isReverse);
    }
    else if (integer === 0)
    {
        digits.push(0);
    }

    return digits;
}

function toDigitsArrayFromString(string, isReverse)
{
    var digits = [];

    string += ""; // Coerce to string.

    var i = null;
    var length = string.length;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1)
    {
        var integer = parseInt(string.charAt(i), 10);
        if (isFinite(integer))
        {
            digits.push(integer);
        }
    }

    if (isReverse)
    {
        digits = reverse(digits);
    }

    return digits;
}
```

Once you have the digits as an array, you can reverse the array easily to get the digits starting from the left or from the right.

The string function is more versatile because it can find any digit in a string, whereas the integer function is limited to integers.

Benchmarks:
http://jsperf.com/todigitsarray

The benchmarks between the two functions show that in Firefox 10 and Chrome 12, the string function is 30% to 60% faster than the integer function. In Opera 12, the integer function is slightly faster by about 10%.

Answer (score 1):

```
//reverse integer
const revInt = (num)=>{
  //turn into string
  if(Math.sign(num)===1)
    return parseInt(num.toString().split('').reverse().join(''));
  else return -1*parseInt(num.toString().split('').reverse().join(''));
}

console.log(revInt(-501));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<script>

function reverseInt(n){

        var r=0;
    while(n!=0){
        r*=10;
        r+=n%10;
        n=Math.floor(n/10);
}
return r;
}


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var n = 352;
function loop(n, r){
    if(!n) return r;
    r = (r ? r * 10 : 0) + n % 10;
    return loop(Math.floor( n / 10), r);
}
console.log(loop(n));
```

Answer (score 0):

**OK,** how about using and chaining these popular tricks in JavaScript in one-line function as below...

```
const reverseNum = num => +("" + ~~num.split("").reverse().join(""));
```

And call it like these:

```
reverseNum(123); //321
reverseNum(423.09); //324
reverseNum(23305.1); //50332
reverseNum(89112); //21198
reverseNum(568434.2389); //434865
```

Answer (score 0):

This takes `Number` x as a parameter and returns the reversed number.

`const reverse = (x) => Number(x.toString().split("").reverse().join(""));`

Answer (score 0):

Memory Usage: 35.3 MB, less than 100.00% of JavaScript online submissions for Reverse Integer on [leetcode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/discuss/248121/The-most-memory-efficient-JS-solution-ever!).
Runtime: 80 ms, faster than 61.48% of JavaScript online submissions for Reverse Integer.

Time complexity is `O(log10(n))`.

```
function reverse(x) {
  let rev = 0;
  const isNegative = Math.sign(x) === -1;
  const isOverflow = n => n > 2**31;
  x = Math.abs(x);

  while (x) {
    let pop = x % 10;
    x = Math.floor(x / 10);
    rev = rev * 10 + pop;

    if (isOverflow(rev)) {
      return 0;
    } 
  }

  return isNegative ? rev * -1 : rev;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The code block below should do the trick

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

var input;

input=window.prompt ("Please enter a number to be reversed.");
x=input.length;

while(x > 0)
{

x=x-1;
document.write(input[x]);

}

</script>
```